# What to grant to user to use index of table while querying?

Tags: oracle, indexing, privileges

I want to know if oracle uses index when user queries data from table and that user has been granted just: 
`grant select on table to user`

I want to know if it is needed some another grant to use index.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there is no requirement (or ability) to grant access to an index.  If the user can access the table then their queries can use any available index.

Comment: my experience this is not true, expecially when the index owner is != from table owner.

Comment: According to https://hemantoracledba.blogspot.com/2009/08/can-query-by-user-c-on-table-owned-by.html this answer is correct.