# Index created under different user

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I created an index on one table column as sys user, as I did not mention the schema name it got created under the sys schema. When I run the query as different user with read access to table I am not seeing the index being used. Could you please let me know whether the index will be ignore in oracle if index is created under different schema?

Comment: For reference, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439529/what-to-grant-to-user-to-use-index-of-table-while-quering Not sure this must be marked as duplicate as the (only) answer is probably not satisfactory. Or is it?

Comment: The answer seems to conflicting, one says yes other one says it does not use.

Comment: I don't have access to any oracle instance at the moment but you could start by reading http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96521/privs.htm#15311. You could also investigate the system views to check if your index is visible there.

Comment: Either way you should move the index back.  Objects created in SYS will probably default to the SYSTEM tablespace, which you don't want to fill up.

Answer (score 3):

The is no permissions specific to index objects. So, as of myself, I would have said that the index will be automatically be used -- even if it is in a different schema. But as a comment on the linked answer raised doubt, I made the experiment using oracle 11g:

As user *sonia*:

```
SQL> create table t as (select level n from dual connect by level < 100);
Table created.

SQL> explain plan for select * from sonia.t where n < 10;
SQL> @UTLXPLS.SQL

TABLE ACCESS FULL T
SELECT STATEMENT

SQL> grant select on t to sylvain;
Grant succeeded.
```

As user *sylvain*:

```
SQL> explain plan for select * from sonia.t where n < 10;
Explained.

SQL> @UTLXPLS.SQL

TABLE ACCESS FULL T
SELECT STATEMENT

SQL> create index syl_idx on sonia.t(n);
Index created.

SQL> explain plan for select * from sonia.t where n < 10;
Explained.

SQL> @UTLXPLS.SQL

INDEX RANGE SCAN SYL_IDX
SELECT STATEMENT
```

Back to *sonia*:

```
SQL> explain plan for select * from sonia.t where n < 10;
Explained.

SQL> @UTLXPLS.SQL

INDEX RANGE SCAN SYL_IDX
SELECT STATEMENT
```

As you can see, `SYL_IDX` (index on *sonia.t* created in the *sylvain* schema) is used both when querying the table from *sonia* and from *sylvain*. Having the select permission *on the table* is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

No, it should not be ignored. There can be other reason considered by the optimizer not to use the index.

It's easy to check that you can use an index in a different schema:

```
-- Connected as power_user
SQL> CREATE TABLE some_user.a_table (a_field INTEGER);
Table created

SQL> INSERT INTO some_user.a_table
  2  SELECT rownum FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= 10000;
10000 rows inserted

SQL> CREATE INDEX power_user.an_index ON some_user.a_table (a_field);
Index created

-- Connected as some_user
SQL> select * from some_user.a_table where a_field = 50;

   A_FIELD
----------
        50


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 573181184

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |          |     1 |    13 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  INDEX RANGE SCAN| AN_INDEX |     1 |    13 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```